# Integrate an Xcode project into another

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I am building an iOS application in Swift 3. It uses a QRCode reader to scan QRCode and I downloaded the [QRCodeReaderViewController](https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReaderViewController).

I am new to iOS. Please help me integrate these files into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the installation process of your QRCodeViewController in the link you provided above. Its clearly mentioned there. You can QRCodeViewController using cocoa pods or manully also.
Adding this line `pod 'QRCodeReaderViewController', '~> 4.0.2'` to pods and pod install u can add QRCodeViewController to your project.

You can even simply drag and drop the QRCodeViewController project in your working project. Just import the required files and implemet the required delegate methods in your class  and you are good to go.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!